# WordPress image url

Tags: wordpress, url

```
$path = bloginfo('template_url');
$image_url = $path.'image.jpg';
```

I do not know why, but `$path = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` is displaying url without `echo`, any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo) automatically displays the property (while returning null). I think you want to use [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo):

```
$path = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
$image_url = $path.'image.jpg';
```

Comment: U can use `template_directory`

Answer (score 1):

You need get_bloginfo() I believe.

Answer (score 1):

**Bloginfo()** always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, try **get_bloginfo()** instead.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `template_directory` instead of `template_url`

```
<?php get_bloginfo('template_directory').'image.jpg'; ?>
```